# HTML text in div go to next line automatically for some text in Android 4.4.2

Tags: android, html, css, ionic-framework

Some text (not all) in the div suddenly go to new line while the text is not reach the max width of the div. For example:
With this long text, in the view it show correctly: "UMI TERIYAKI & SUSHI", this text is placed on the same line in my div.
My HTML:

```
<listitem><div style="width: 100%;background-color: white; margin-bottom: 1px;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="row font-weight-bold ng-binding">UMI TERIYAKI & SUSHI</div>
      <div class="row ng-binding">MONTREAL ROAD</div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
</listitem>
```

Result in browser:

```
UMI TERIYAKI & SUSHI
MONTREAL ROAD
```

But with this shorter text: "MACS SUSHI", "MACS" and "SUSHI" are placed on two seperated lines in my div => I expect these text are placed on the same line too because the text length is not reach the max width of div no need to go to the new line.
My HTML:

```
<listitem><div style="width: 100%;background-color: white; margin-bottom: 1px;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="row font-weight-bold ng-binding">MACS SUSHI</div>
      <div class="row ng-binding">BAYSHORE DRIVE</div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
</listitem>
```

Result in browser:

```
MACS
SUSHI
BAYSHORE DRIVE
```

Comment: Hello. You should add more context so we could better understand. Are you using Cordova? Or a vanilla web-view? Could you a complete extract of your html? At least the div and its parent. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time asking on this website, i edited the question, please help me if you have any idea

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste the code?

**Edit**
There's no problem with the code in the div.  The `<listitem>` and `<div>`'s are fine themselves.

It's more likely the width of the div on the page is the problem.  But I don't know for sure without seeing more of the code.

You could try giving the `<div>` in question a background color to clearly see it's actual size.

Comment: I think @brt meant the CSS code as well, it would be helpful for instance to know what's int CSS class col, or row and so on... 

I think you already solved your problem but maybe you should avoid using '&' directly, you should rather use &#38; because & is a reserved xml char for xml entities.